# Runtime error SIGSEGV infix to postfix

Tags: c++, runtime, iostream, segmentation-fault

This code works fine on my machine but when i upload it to codechef it gives me a runtime error SIGSEGV. Can anyone please point out the error in my code? This is the question i made it for http://www.codechef.com/problems/ONP/

```
#include<iostream>  
#include<string>  
using namespace std;  
class stack  
{  
    public:  
        void push(char a)  
        {  
            ++top;    
            arr[top]=a;  
        }  
        void pop()  
        {  
            top--;  
        }  
        void initialize(int size)  
        {  
            top=-1;  
            max=size;  
        }  
        bool chckfull()  
        {  
            return (top==max-1);  
        }  
        bool chckempty()  
        {  
            return (top==-1);  
        }  
        char front()  
        {  
            return arr[top];  
        }  
        private:  
            int top;  
            int max;  
            char arr[404];  
};  
int chckalphanum(char y)  
{  
    if((y>='a')&&(y<='z'))  
    return 1;  
    else if ((y>='A')&&(y<'Z'))  
    return 1;  
    else if((y>='0')&&(y<='9'))  
    return 1;  
    return 0;  
}  
int pre(char x)  
{  
    if(chckalphanum(x))  
    return 0;  
    if(x=='(')  
    return -1;  
    else if(x=='^')  
    return 3;  
    else if((x=='/')||(x=='*'))  
    return 2;  
    else  
    return 1;  
}  
int main ()  
{  
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);  
    string s, s1=")";  
    char q[404];  
    int qmax=0,t;  
    stack prs;  
    scanf("%d", &t);  
    while(t--)  
    {  
    cin>>s;  
    prs.initialize(s.length());  
    prs.push('(');  
    s=s+s1;  
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)  
    {  
        if(s[i]=='(')  
        prs.push('(');  
        else if(chckalphanum(s[i]))  
        {  
            q[qmax]=s[i];  
            qmax++;  
        }  
        else if(s[i]==')')  
        {  
            while(prs.front()!='(')  
            {  
                q[qmax]=prs.front();  
                qmax++;  
                prs.pop();  
            }  
            prs.pop();  
        }  
        else  
        {  
             while(pre(prs.front())>=pre(s[i]))  
             {  
                q[qmax]=prs.front();  
                qmax++;  
                prs.pop();  
             }  
             prs.push(s[i]);  
        }  
    }  
    for(int i=0; i<qmax; i++)  
    cout<<q[i];  
    cout<<"\n";  
    qmax=0;  
    }  
return 0;  
}
```

Comment: I do. I have written an initialize function. And initialized top to -1.

Comment: And I have also called that function. just after taking my string input.

Comment: My bad - I missed that - normally you would expect to see initialisation in a constructor. The code crashes for me though so you should be able to debug it off-line. See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ccb8bc96c7a72a1

Comment: Actually i tried that on dev c++. Its working perfectly. Thats why i am stuck.

Comment: Try it with a proper compiler - see link above.

Comment: it shows an error in i<s.length(). But i have used it so many times and in so many instances. :/

Comment: That's just a compile warning (which you should fix, but it doesn't matter too much for now) - the seg fault on the next line is the run-time error.

Comment: Yes yes, i get it now! Let me check the error.! Thank you so much for your time :) Its a big code

Comment: Unless you somehow reach the limits (seriously, your stack should do some bounds-checking, and you may replace the array with a vector using `at()` to check as well), I don't see anything immediately *wrong*.

Comment: Is bound checking necessary in this? Because it wont get empty ever. I added an extra parenthesis in the starting to be sure. Same for full. And ok, i'll try replacing it with vector

Comment: @PranjalRanjan Bounds checking is unnecessary only if you can be sure that you never create code with errors in it. You should at least make sure that you don't push onto a full stack or pop off an empty one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just commented out the below line from your solution and it got accepted in codechef.

`std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);`

I am not sure if you are aware of what the above line does but I will try to explain to the best of my knowledge. Better answers will definitely follow in due course from the community.

"With stdio synchronization turned off, iostream standard stream objects may operate independently of the standard C streams (although they are not required to), and mixing operations may result in unexpectedly interleaved characters."

Quoting from cppreference.

"Concurrent access to the same stream object may cause data races."

Since you have turned off the synchronization between stdio (C style I/O) and iostream (C++ style I/O)
and you continued using  `scanf`  and  `cin`  simultaneously interleaved, I suspect you got a runtime error.

For more research, please go through :  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/sync_with_stdio/

Hope it clarifies a bit, if not fully. Thanks!

Comment: thank you..! You are absolutely right! Thanks a lot! :-)